# When using go-cron to work, multiple services are started at the same time, and multiple cron tasks will be executed at the same time?

Tags: go, cron

When using go-cron to work, multiple services are started at the same time, and multiple cron tasks will be executed at the same time? What can be done to ensure that the cron task is only executed once?

my cron expression is [0 2 */1 * *]

Comment: is not really clear to me what do you what to achieve. Do you already see the SingletonMode https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#Scheduler.SingletonMode ? the `SingletonModeAll` permit to run only one task at the time https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#Scheduler.SingletonModeAll

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the `SingletonMode` for your task to prevents a new job from starting if the prior job has not yet completed:

```
    s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    _, _ = s.Every(1).Second().SingletonMode().Do(task)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#Scheduler.SingletonMode

Or enable the `SingletonModeAll` to prevent new jobs from starting if the prior instance of the particular job has not yet completed:

```
    s := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    s.SingletonModeAll()

    _, _ = s.Every(1).Second().Do(task)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-co-op/gocron#Scheduler.SingletonModeAll